# Write a narcissist program!

Tags: code-golf, quine

A narcissist program is simple.  It is related to a quine.

If the input is equal to it's source code, it prints a truthy value, if not it prints a falsy one.  That is it.

Rules:

- It can't read it's own file.
- This is code-golf, so the shortest answer wins.
- Hash functions are *not* allowed.  This trivializes it into just string matching.
- The submission may be a function.

An example would be:

Code:

```
someprogramhere
```

Input:

```
someprogramhere
```

Output:

```
1
```

Or input:

```
a
```

Output:

```
0
```

Your code most certainly won't be `someprogramhere`, but you get the idea.

Go code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## JavaScript ES6, 14 bytes

```
$=_=>_==`$=`+$
```

Simple modification of the traditional "bling quine".